# My app crashes when clicking on a button to start a new activity

Tags: java, android

Whenever I click the button to go to the next activity the app crashes, no matter what I change in the code it still has the same problem.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private Button b;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    onClickButtonListener();
  }
  public void onClickButtonListener(){
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent("SecondActivity");
        startActivity(i);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Mainfest

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".SecondActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
</application>
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent("SecondActivity");
```

This should be

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of This.

```
Intent i = new Intent("SecondActivity");
```

Use like this.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Perhaps this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code..

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class))
```